# How to find radius of circle quarter ... given inside it rectangle

Tags: geometry

How to find radius of circle quarter ... given inside it rectangle
i think more in getting quarter area with ... i get area with radius from side and i get area with another side and make them equal each other but doesn't fit

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U86Dx.png

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: i do , i  get area with radius from side and i get area with another side and make them equal each other but doesn't fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the radius be $r$.  The side lengths of the rectangle are $r-1$ and $r-2$.  The diagonal is $r$.  By the Pythagorean theorem we have

$$(r-1)^2+(r-2)^2=r^2$$

Which expands and simplifies to

$$r^2-6r + 5 = (r-5)(r-1) = 0$$

So $r=1$, or $r=5$.  But, looking at the diagram again we see that the radius must be at least $2$, so $r=5$ is the answer.